# How to iterate over a list of object in drools decision table?

Tags: drools, jbpm

```
Class A{

public List<B> list;

public String ind;

}

Class B{

public String ind;

}
```

I have requirement to iterate over a list of objects( in this case list of B objects present under class A)and check for a field inside all objects(ind in class B), If any of the object contains that particular field value non null, stop the loop and set the ind field value in class A.

Answer (score 0):

Using rules, as long as you provide the necessary objects to working memory, you won't have to loop - the Drools engine will take care of this for you.

The following rule will find objects of B from A's list and set A's Ind to B's Ind value:

```
rule "Set B Value"
when
    $a: A()
    $b: B($bInd: ind, $bInd == "someValue") from $a.list
then
    $a.setInd($bInd);
end
```

Comment: And in an xls decision table, how could it be done?

Comment: @Luis Fernando Prudencio Cruz, were you able to find a solution for this. I also have a similar work to do. It would be helpful, if you share your insights.